# Controller action is not being called?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, php

My controller is being called but not the action. Here is my code:

```
    <?php


class Excellence_Mobile_RestController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "Hello World";
    }

    public function testAction() {
        echo 'iiiii';
        die;
    }
}
```

Here is config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Excellence_Mobile>
            <version>0.1.10</version>
        </Excellence_Mobile>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mobile>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Excellence_Mobile</module>
                    <frontName>excellence</frontName>
                </args>
            </mobile>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mobile>
                    <file>mobile.xml</file>
                </mobile>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <mobile>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Excellence_Mobile</module>
                    <frontName>mobile</frontName>
                </args>
            </mobile>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <mobile module="mobile">
                <title>Excellence</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <mobileapp>
                        <title>Mobile App</title>
                        <children>
                            <homepage>
                                <title>Home Page</title>
                                <children>
                                    <items module="mobile">
                                        <title>Home Page Products</title>
                                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                        <action>mobile/adminhtml_mobile</action>
                                    </items>
                                </children>
                            </homepage>    
                            <homecat>
                                <title>Home Page Category</title>
                                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                <action>mobile/adminhtml_category</action>
                            </homecat>
                        </children>
                    </mobileapp>
                </children>
            </mobile>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>  
                    <children>
                        <Excellence_Mobile>
                            <title>Mobile Module</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </Excellence_Mobile>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <mobilesection translate="title" module="mobile">
                                            <title>Mobile</title>
                                            <sort_order>99</sort_order>
                                        </mobilesection>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>    
                    </children>

                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mobile>
                    <file>mobile.xml</file>
                </mobile>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>   
    <global>

        <cache>
            <types>
                <mobile_cache module="your_module" translate="label description">
                    <label>Mobile App Cache</label>
                    <description>Mobile App Cache.</description>
                    <tags>mobile_cache</tags>
                </mobile_cache>
            </types>
        </cache>


        <models>
          <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_type_price>Excellence_Mobile_Model_Price</product_type_price>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>


        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer_grid>Excellence_Mobile_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid</customer_grid>
                    <sales_order_grid>Excellence_Mobile_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
                </rewrite>

            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>

        <rewrite>
            <mobile_customer_account> 
                <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/account/#]]></from>  
                <to>/mobile/account/</to>  
            </mobile_customer_account>

            <mobile_cache_clear> 
                <from><![CDATA[#^/admin/cache/#]]></from>
                <to>/mobile/adminhtml_cache/</to>  

            </mobile_cache_clear>

        </rewrite>

        <events>
            <admin_system_config_section_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <excellence_mobile_admin_system_config_section_save_after>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Excellence_Mobile_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>adminsection</method>
                    </excellence_mobile_admin_system_config_section_save_after>
                </observers>
            </admin_system_config_section_save_after>

            <adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data>
                <observers>
                    <modulename>
                        <class>Excellence_Mobile_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data</method>
                    </modulename>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data>
            <sales_convert_quote_to_order>
                <observers>
                    <modulename>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>Excellence_Mobile_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>sales_convert_quote_to_order</method> 
                    </modulename>
                </observers>
            </sales_convert_quote_to_order>


            <catalog_product_get_frontend_final_price>
                <observers>
                    <modulename>
                        <class>Excellence_Mobile_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>getFrontFinalPrice</method>
                    </modulename>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_get_frontend_final_price>

        </events>
        <models>
            <mobile>
                <class>Excellence_Mobile_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mobile_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </mobile>   

            <mobile_mysql4>
                <class>Excellence_Mobile_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <csrf>
                        <table>mobile_csrf</table>
                    </csrf> 
                    <jwt>
                        <table>mobile_jwt</table>
                    </jwt>
                </entities>
            </mobile_mysql4>
            <slider>
                <rewrite>
                    <slides>Excellence_Mobile_Model_Slider</slides>
                </rewrite>
            </slider>
        </models>


        <resources>
            <mobile_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Excellence_Mobile</module>
                    <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </mobile_setup>
            <mobile_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </mobile_write>
            <mobile_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </mobile_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <mobile>
                <class>Excellence_Mobile_Block</class>
            </mobile>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_history>Excellence_Mobile_Block_Order_History</order_history>
                    <order_recent>Excellence_Mobile_Block_Order_Recent</order_recent>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>


        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <mobile>
                <class>Excellence_Mobile_Helper</class>
            </mobile>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Show your URL which you are called?

Comment: I am using http://megashopping.am/index.php/excellence/rest/index

Comment: when i put die in controller then it works but it doesn't work in action.

Comment: Whats your `frontname`?

Comment: domain.com/frontname/controller_name/action_name.

Comment: it's excellence

Comment: I am doing the same.

Comment: If i click on that url you have provided its giving me 404.

Comment: that is the problem, its not going in action

Comment: if i put die in class or preDispatch, then it works

Comment: Add config.xml code here too.

Comment: I have added, Please check

Comment: same code is working on other server, but not here

Comment: Do you have compilation enabled in your site?

Comment: no, its not enabled

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to check following things.

1. No spaces in etc/config.xml
2. Your module is enabled in app/etc/modules/namespace_module.xml
3. Make sure your module is active and available there

   `System > Configuration > Advanced`
4. Check log files
5. Check if you have store in your url under

   `System > Configuration > Web > Url Options > Add Store Code to Urls.`

Comment: have done all this. But its not working on this server. It was working on other servers perfectly.